# How to handle system limit exception

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting this limit exception : System.LimitException:Too many callouts: 11

when I make a callout as this exception can not be catch, can someone help me how to handle this exception on visualforce page

any help will be appreciated.. Thanks

Comment: Can you share some of your (controller) code - like where you are performing the callouts ? You'll most likely need to change your implementation design.

Comment: I made a callout after 1 second  on KeyUp event so if user press keys more than 10, it throws this error.

Comment: You could keep track of your callouts, and limit them when you're at 9 if this is all in one VF view context. Alternativly you could process every keyUp with remote Javascript which will give you a fresh set of governor limits for its execution.

Comment: thanks for the help.. can you provide me some code for remote javascript..

Comment: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot catch limit exceptions. Instead you need to prevent causing one. You can use the Limits class methods to find out how many callouts you have remaining.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_limits.htm

Call Limits.getLimitCallouts() and check that this is greater than 0 before making a callout.

As Sdry has said, it sounds like you may need to refactor your design

Comment: Thanks for the help.. I try it, if it is helpful to me..