# Governor Limit Exception and Finally blocks

Tags: apex, governorlimits, try-catch

We all know that if you hit a Governor Limit Exception, your code/application will terminate with an unhandleable exception know as a Governor Limit Exception.

My question is does your code terminated at the point at which the limit is exceeded? If so, even if you have a finally block, it will not get run since your code has terminated?

Comment: Yes, code terminated at the point at which the limit is exceeded and finally block will not be executed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle system limit exception](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/16872/how-to-handle-system-limit-exception)

Comment: The proposed duplicate does not answer this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hit a `LimitException`, it terminates the entire transaction. No other `Apex` code you have written will run within the same transaction, because it is over.

Answer (score 3):

@M guy I Have gone through your doubt and found this:-

I have a class as follows;-

```
public class testGoverner {
Public static void insertcontact(){
    try{
        for(Integer i=0;i<1500;i++){
            Contact c = new Contact();
            c.LastName='system'+i;
            insert c;
        }
    }catch(DmlException e){
        system.debug(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally{
        system.debug('Hit the governer limit');
    }
}
```

}
When I run this class using execute annonymous window, I got error **System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101**

So, I tried calling this in another class as follows:-

```
public class TestClas {
public static void test(){
    try{
    system.debug('check');
    testGoverner.insertcontact();
    }finally{
        system.debug('hit governer');
    }
}
```

}

And again run it, so again I got the same error **System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101**

So in both the cases, it gets terminated without going to finally block and no debugs log got generated.

then I tried calling this class with Visualforce page and execute it on click of button as follows:-

```
<apex:page controller="testGoverner">
<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
    <apex:pageBlockButtons>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!insertcontact}" value="check"/>
    </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

And Got this:- Too many DML statements: 151
Error is in expression '{!insertcontact}' in component  in page testgovern: Class.testGoverner.insertcontact: line 7, column 1

This time debug log get generated but finally statement does not get executed.
Note:- **even catch block does not get executed**.

So I can say you are correct that your code terminated at the point at which the limit is exceeded.  Even if you have a finally block, it will not get run since your code has terminated.